# I get an "Error: Cannot initialize OLE" when I try to connect to a database? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-connection, ole

I'm trying to connect to a database via C#, but I'm getting a very unhelpful error message when I do so:

"08:44:17: Error: Cannot initialize OLE
08:44:17: Error: Cannot initialize OLE"

I've tried looking for a solution, but I've been unsuccessful. I also tried restarting my computer, which didn't help either.

I am running SQL Server 2008, and here is the relevant database code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Connects to a given database and returns the database connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">The database file name.</param>
    /// <returns>The database connection.</returns>
    public static SqlConnection ConnectToDb(string file)
    {
        //initialize generic path
        string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        path = path.Replace("bin\\Debug\\MediaPlayer.exe", "");
        path += "Database.mdf";

        string connectionPath = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + path + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionPath);
        return connection;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a SQL query in a given database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">The database file name.</param>
    /// <param name="query">The SQL query to execute.</param>
    public static void ExecuteQuery(string file, string query)
    {

        SqlConnection connection = ConnectToDb(file);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

This is database code that I have used for several project, and it has always worked before.

The error is called (I know this because I commented out other lines) on the connection.Open() line in the ExecuteQuery method.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated :).

EDIT: I tested my connection to the database and everything checked out, I just don't understand why I can't connect via code.

Comment: 1st off... open SSMS and try to connect to sqlexpress.

Comment: How do I open SSMS? Sorry, I'm inexperienced :P.. It doesn't appear as a program nor a toolbar in Visual Studio..

Comment: SSMS is the user interface shipped with the sql server. So you open Microsoft SQL Management Studio, connect to your server and see if the sql server works in general.

Comment: @Daniel why you connect like this and not to the sql server directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who might be looking, I eventually solved this by adding a [STAThread()] before the Main() method. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are building the project for x64 CPU. There is no OLE driver for x64. I recommend to change the build target from ANY CPU to x86.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I opened the project properties and opened the "Build" panel, and under Platform the selected option is "Active (x86)".. In fact, that's the only option.

Comment: I'm running 64-bit Windows 7.